# Yahoo DotNetAutho SSO Login: prevent Yahoo from creating a popup

Tags: .net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I am using the DotNetOpenAuth library to create an SSO login for Google and Yahoo. I am redirecting to the provider programatically, using Request.RedirectToProvider() when the user clicks on my LinkButton (I am using a custom login control).

This works fine for Google and Yahoo in all browsers. The problem is that Yahoo seems to think it's being opened in a popup, and resizes the entire window.

How do I set the UI type in DotNetOpenAuth to prevent this behavior? UIModes only seems to have the Popup mode?

Edit: I haven't actually used the UIRequest extension. That was part of my debugging effort.

The request code is as follows:

```
Dim OpenIDEndpoint As String = WellKnownProviders.Yahoo.ToString, OpenID As OpenIdRelyingParty = New OpenIdRelyingParty
    Dim LoginRequest As IAuthenticationRequest = OpenID.CreateRequest(OpenIDEndpoint)

    Dim Fields As ClaimsRequest = New ClaimsRequest()

    Fields.Email = DemandLevel.Require
    Fields.FullName = DemandLevel.Require
    Fields.Nickname = DemandLevel.Require
    Fields.BirthDate = DemandLevel.Require
    Fields.Gender = DemandLevel.Require

    LoginRequest.AddExtension(Fields)
    LoginRequest.RedirectToProvider()
```

Answer (score 0):

The UI extension is strictly for use by popups.  If you aren't opening the Provider's login page in a popup, don't attach the `UIRequest` extension.

I expect that will solve the resizing issue.

Comment: It's really strange, I haven't actually used the UIRequest extension (I was only trying to fix the behavior with it after the problem occurred). I don't know why Yahoo assumes it's in a popup. Anywhere else I might be accidentally setting this value?

Answer (score 0):

Felt this was better presented in an answer than a comment:

Even StackOverflow's Yahoo login page has the same problem!

On checking SSO's Yahoo's login link, I noticed that Yahoo's SSO login page seems to be optimized for popup logins. On the page, there's this JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isPopup = "true"; //<-- Note this
if (window.opener || isPopup) {
  var Dom = YAHOO.util.Dom;
  var Event = YAHOO.util.Event;

  (function() {
    if (Dom.getViewportWidth() < 500 || Dom.getViewportHeight() < 675) {
        window.resizeTo(500,675);
    }
  })();

...
```

Even though SSO doesn't use popups, Yahoo seems to be setting the isPopup value to true. I don't know if this is an error on the part of Yahoo, or some bug/error in DotNetOpenAuth. I would welcome Andrew's views on this?

**Update**:

Weird, SSO ate my update.

http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-userauth.html - Yahoo apparently has optimized their SSO login page ONLY for popups. The window resizing is probably a result of this.